# Complexity of exponentiation algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Given `double x` and positive `int y` I need to find `x^y` assuming the input will not cause an overflow.

I came up with an algorithm that uses the following facts about `x^y`:

1. `x^y=(x^floor(y/2))^2` if y is even.
2. `x^y=x*(x^floor(y/2))^2` if y is odd.
3. `x^y=1` if y is 0

The implementation:

```
public static double power(double x, int y) {
    if(y==0)
      return 1;

    double z=power(x, y>>>1);
    z*=z;
    if((y&1)==1)
      z*=x;

    return z;
  }
```

I'm somewhat struggling with its complexity analysis. There're `log_2(y)` recursion levels and no branching. At each level the algorithm squares `z`, the multiplication complexity is `O(n^2)` where `n` is the number of bits in `z`. We assume that no overflow can happen, hence `n` is at most half of that in the `double` type. Do I count this multiplication work as constant, which gives the algorithm's complexity of `O(log_2(y))`?

Comment: "`x^y=x^floor(y/2)`if y is even" Well, no. You can easily see that that's not true. Probably you forgot a `^2` somewhere in that formula.

Comment: I did forget it:( fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the algorithm is in fact called [binary exponentiation](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html) and the complexity of it is `log_2(y)`as you mentioned. Multiplication of two numbers will usually be considered `O(1)` unless the number can be arbitrarily large (also called BigInt). This is because the number of bits of a number are always constant.

### Note

Also, although not entirely related to the question, I saw that you mentioned multiplication complexity is `O(n)` for number of n bits. This is not true. The normal way of multiplying number is actually `O(n^2)`. But in fact we can do better than that with some fast multiplication algorithm. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Note that `O(log_2(y))` is the same as `O(log(y))`.

Comment: I meant O(n^2) for the multiplication.

Comment: Typically, hardware multiplication is counted as a constant operation: O(1).

Answer (score 1):

1. You will do a maximum of log2(Y) loops

   - After the nth loop, y is divided n times by two at least because ​for each loop y is replaced by floor(y/2) which is lower than y/2
     ​ - log2(y) is such that 2^log2(y)=y
   - you make a maximum of log2(y)+1 loop because after log2(y) loops y is replaced by floor(y/y/2)=0
2. Each loop has a constat time of execution
3. Therefore you will have a O(log2(y)) complexity